# wxpython two panel layout

Tags: wxpython

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,size=(250, 250))

        panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1,pos=(0,100),size=(100,100))
        button1 = wx.Button(panel1, -1, label="click me")

        panel2 = wx.Panel(self, -1,pos=(0,200))
        button2 = wx.Button(panel2, -1, label="click me")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel1,0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border=10)
        sizer.Add(panel2,0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border=10)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)



class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
         frame.Show(True)
         return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

I want to test two panel layout in wxpython , i change the pos(x,y) but it does't work . so
how to layout just use boxsizer and panel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking. If you use a sizer, then you cannot provide x/y coordinates to position the widgets. If you're just wondering why the panels look weird, it's because you don't have a normal panel underneath them. The code below is one way to fix that. The other way would be to give each of the panels you had a proportion greater than zero when adding them to the BoxSizer.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,size=(250, 250))

        topPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        panel1 = wx.Panel(topPanel, -1,pos=(0,100),size=(100,100))
        button1 = wx.Button(panel1, -1, label="click me")

        panel2 = wx.Panel(topPanel, -1,pos=(0,200))
        button2 = wx.Button(panel2, -1, label="click me")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel1,0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border=10)
        sizer.Add(panel2,0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border=10)

        topPanel.SetSizer(sizer)



class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
         frame.Show(True)
         return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: **If you use a sizer, then you cannot provide x/y coordinates to position the widgets** this is the problem i didn't notice , thanks! Anyway , i learn python with your blog ~~

Comment: Add two different colors makes it clear where the two panels are ^^
`panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#6f8089')`

Comment: Yes, that's one good way to check panel positioning. Another is to use the Widget Inspection Tool.

Comment: You are missing `app.MainLoop()` at the end of your code :)